# solve this differential equation $y^3\cdot y''+Ay^4+B=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A,B$ be constant numbers, solve this differential equation
$$y^3\cdot y''+Ay^4+B=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^3\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}+Ay^4+B=0$$
This is a second order non-linear ODE of autonomous kind. A usual method of solving is a change of function and variable :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y) \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y)\frac{df}{dy}$$
So, the new unknown is the function $f$ and the new variable is $y$
$$y^3f(y)\frac{df}{dy}+Ay^4+B=0$$
$$2f(y)\frac{df}{dy}+2Ay+2By^{-3}=0$$
$$\int 2f\frac{df}{dy}dy+A\int 2ydy+B\int 2y^{-3}dy=0$$
$$(f(y))^2+Ay^2-B^{-2}=c_1$$
$$f(y)=\sqrt{c_1-Ay^2+By^{-2}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{c_1-Ay^2+By^{-2}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{c_1-Ay^2+By^{-2}}}=dx$$
$$\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{c_1-Ay^2+By^{-2}}} = x+c_2$$

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, divide by $y^3$, multiply by $2y'$, integrate to obtain
$$
y'^2+Ay^2-By^{-2}=C
$$

Comment: Well done. Simpler than I did.

Comment: Both methods are largely equivalent, at least for conservative equations that can be written as $y''=a(y)$. For $y''=f(y,y')$ your method still gives an equation for $F(y)$, however in general no explicit integration will be possible.